# Shell "|&" syntax not recognized in ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I am running a shell command in ansible playbook in which I want to store the last line of the output But getting below error:

> fatal: [webserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "**./hash.sh -p admin123 |& tail -1**", "delta": "0:00:00.002563", "end": "2019-06-06 16:25:56.597951", "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2019-06-06 16:25:56.595388", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"&\" unexpected", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"&\" unexpected"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

**main.yaml**

```
- name: Get hash value of admin password
  shell: "./hash.sh -p {{admin_password}} |& tail -1"
  args:
    chdir: /usr/share/tools
  register: admin_password_hash
```

It gives me correct output when I run that command (`./hash.sh -p admin123 |& tail -1`) directly on the remote machine.

Comment: `|&` is not valid `/bin/sh` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean `|&` to be redirecting stderr through the pipe, the POSIX-compliant alternative to `cmd1 |& cmd2` (thus, the way that works with `/bin/sh`) is `cmd1 2>&1 | cmd2`:

```
- name: "Get hash value of admin password"
  shell: "./hash.sh -p {{admin_password | quote}} 2>&1 | tail -1"
  args:
    chdir: /usr/share/tools
  register: admin_password_hash
```

That `| quote` is important: You have potential for major security problems without it, insofar as someone who chose `$(rm -rf /*)` as their password could cause your whole system to be wiped. (I'd hazard that's the password used by [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)!)